# How to make static variable to non-static to use in multiple classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Hi I have selenium tests with two classes and I am using a variable that is static. But when I run the test in parallel the variable is used between test runs and the test results are failing due to incorrect value in the variable. I am trying to make that variable as non-static but it's throwing an error

```
package test.stepdefinitions.dartts;

import test.dartts.pom.FilterGroup_POM;
import test.utility.ScenarioContext;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.*;

import static test.resources.base.getDriver;

public class FilterGroup {
    private final ScenarioContext sc;
    final WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    public String newFilterGroupName;
    public static String filterGroupNameForTest;
    public static Map<String, String> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static Map<String, String> filterChipMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> dataSourcesList = new ArrayList<>();
   @When("I click new filter group")
    public void i_click_new_filter_group() {
        FilterGroup_POM i = new FilterGroup_POM(driver);
        Random random = new Random();
        newFilterGroupName = "AutoTestFG " + random.nextInt(1000);
        if (i.isFirstFilterGroupPresent(newFilterGroupName)) {
        String filterName = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(text(),'" + newFilterGroupName + "')])[1]")).getText();
        filterMap.put("filterGroupNameForTest", newFilterGroupName);
        System.out.println("Filter group name for test automation: " + newFilterGroupName);
        i.clickOnNewFilterGroupBtn();
    }
}
```

Second class

```
package test.stepdefinitions.common;
import test.common.pom.Common_Login_POM;
import test.stepdefinitions.dartts.FilterGroup;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import static gov.dhs.ice.raven.resources.base.getDriver;

public class Common_Login {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
 
   @Then("I should log out of Raven app")
    public void i_should_log_out_of_raven_app() {
        Common_Login_POM i = new Common_Login_POM(driver);
        i.clickLogout();
        if (!FilterGroup.filterMap.isEmpty()){
            FilterGroup.filterMap.clear();
            FilterGroup.dataSourcesList.clear();
            FilterGroup.filterChipMap.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

If I make this `public static Map<String, String> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();` from the first class as non-static then the `FilterGroup.filterMap.isEmpty()` is throwing error as Non-static field 'filterMap' cannot be referenced from a static context

One another issue this line `newFilterGroupName = "AutoTestFG " + random.nextInt(1000);` is to generate a  string by adding a random 3 digits to it. But when I run the same test 5 times in parallel it created the name for the first test and same was used on subsequent tests instead of create new one for each. Am I missing anything here.

I tried to remove the static from the first class and I want the variable "filterMap" in second class to be identified and work as normal.

Answer (score 3):

So, in a nutshell, you want to share the state between 2 steps that are located in different classes within a single scenario.

See [the official documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/?lang=java) about sharing the state. Basically, you need to use the dependency injection, which will help you to inject a 'ScenarioContext' into all your step definition classes. The 'ScenarioContext' class will be responsible for holding the required properties (filterMap, childMap etc)

There are a lot of ways of doing it, but I'd recommend you to use [PicoContainer](http://picocontainer.com/).
See [this article](https://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) to understand the logic behind the framework.

Regarding the unique num generation, see that answer from @thou mother (about using ThreadLocalRandom)

Comment: Thanks @sashkins, I am already using ScenarioContext for some other data. I will try to modify these variables also to use the SC and will let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are doing, but one solution to your static issue is to create a global instance of your `FilterGroup` class, and then use that to reference `FilterMap`, like so:

```java
package test.stepdefinitions.dartts;

import test.dartts.pom.FilterGroup_POM;
import test.utility.ScenarioContext;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.*;

import static test.resources.base.getDriver;

public class FilterGroup {
    public static FilterGroup filterGroup = new FilterGroup();
    private final ScenarioContext sc;
    final WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    public String newFilterGroupName;
    public static String filterGroupNameForTest;
    public Map<String, String> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static Map<String, String> filterChipMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> dataSourcesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @When("I click new filter group")
    public void i_click_new_filter_group() {
        FilterGroup_POM i = new FilterGroup_POM(driver);
        Random random = new Random();
        newFilterGroupName = "AutoTestFG " + random.nextInt(1000);
        if (i.isFirstFilterGroupPresent(newFilterGroupName)) {
            String filterName = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(text(),'" + newFilterGroupName + "')])[1]")).getText();
            filterMap.put("filterGroupNameForTest", newFilterGroupName);
            System.out.println("Filter group name for test automation: " + newFilterGroupName);
            i.clickOnNewFilterGroupBtn();
        }
    }
}
```

And your Common_Login class (side note, this should not have an underscore, in java it is typical to use `CamelCase` for class names, so I would reconsider naming this class to `CommonLogin`):

```java
package test.stepdefinitions.common;
import test.common.pom.Common_Login_POM;
import test.stepdefinitions.dartts.FilterGroup;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import static gov.dhs.ice.raven.resources.base.getDriver;

public class Common_Login {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();

    @Then("I should log out of Raven app")
    public void i_should_log_out_of_raven_app() {
        Common_Login_POM i = new Common_Login_POM(driver);
        i.clickLogout();
        if (!FilterGroup.filterGroup.filterMap.isEmpty()){
            FilterGroup.filterGroup.filterMap.clear();
            FilterGroup.dataSourcesList.clear();
            FilterGroup.filterChipMap.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to turn `FilterMap` into a non-static member of `FilterGroup`

Secondly, I would use the following to generate random numbers:

```java
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 999 + 1)
```

This should generate random numbers, and will perform better than nextInt, as in theory, `Random().nextInt(1000)` can still generate numbers that are under 100 (less than the 3 digit threshold you require).